# bash script: safe way to concatenate 2 files where the output is also an input?

Tags: bash, file, concatenation

If I have 2 files `file1`, `file2`, can I concatantate them in bash in a safe manner such that one of `file1` or `file2` is the output file as well as the input?

For example:

```
$ cat file1 file2 >> file2
```

Produces:

```
$ cat: file2: input file is output file
```

I guess this means what I am doing is not "safe".

This also suprises me - how does cat know about `file2` after the `>>` "operator". The second question here is how does `>>` work in bash? Does it store data in a temporary location before "redirecting/saving" it to the file which follows the operator?

Comment: You can't append to a file you are reading from. Output to a third file then `mv` the third file to the second file. `>>` doesn't write to a buffer; it writes to a file, thus the need for a new file to dump the `cat` output. Linux is all based on files.

Comment: [sponge](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/sponge.1.html) from the moreutils package can help out, if you want to install an additional package.

Comment: The shell opens `file2` for output before it starts `cat`, but `cat` is perfectly able to inspect its stdout and tell (1) if it's a file, and (2) which file it is.

Comment: @glennjackman, even though `sponge -a` exists, it's a much more expensive operation if we're talking about a big file, since it's rewriting the output file from the very beginning, as opposed to writing only from the append point.

Answer (score 3):

#### Workaround

The following *safely* works around your issue:

```
cat file1 <(dd if=file2 bs="$(wc -c <file2)" count=1) >> file2
```

#### Explanation

If `cat` didn't have a safeguard here (and some implementations don't!), you would have an endless loop -- where there would forever be more information in `file2` (because `cat`'s own output is being appended to it), so the append operation would never stop.

`dd if=file2 bs=SIZE_OF_FILE2 count=1` emits only the number of bytes present in `file2` *as of the point in time when your command is started*, so it avoids this endless loop. Also, because `cat` is reading from a process substitution, it can't detect that `file2` is the source of the content, so it doesn't trip the error.

Comment: I haven't tested, but would that command line actually work? On my systems, `wc -c file2` inclues the filename.

Comment: Nice point about the endless loop. For reference, you can "trick" cat (for Science!) by running it in a subshell, to make its eventual output undetectable: `(cat foo bar) > bar`. In my test, this produced a `bar` that contained the repeated contents of `foo`, with no sign of the original `bar`.

Comment: @ghoti, ...I'm surprised that works -- that the given redirection was performed before the shell that invoked `cat` it was started, rather than just before that shell starts `cat`, wouldn't (I'd expect) make any difference to a detection process that was introspecting the file descriptor passed on stdout from within `cat`'s startup. Are you sure you were testing this on a platform where that detection is available in the first place? (It's not available in MacOS's `cat`, for instance).

Comment: @ghoti, ...and running GNU `cat` *on* MacOS, the detection appears to still work: `$ (gcat file1 file2) >> file2` properly fails with `gcat: file2: input file is output file`

Comment: @ghoti, ...now, what *would* bypass the detection (but potentially produce an endless output file, depending on how large file2 is and how the race comes out) is `cat file1 <(cat file2) >> file2`.

Comment: The command I suggested above behaves the same on FreeBSD in both bash and /bin/sh (which is an ash derivative, only relevant regarding redirection). And `ident /bin/cat` in macOS reports: `$FreeBSD: src/bin/cat/cat.c,v 1.32 2005/01/10 08:39:20 imp Exp $` which would be about the era of FreeBSD version 5.0. And to confirm what you said, I get the same result from a simple `cat foo bar > bar` -- ongoing repetition of the contents of `foo` in `bar`.

Comment: Also interestingly, `cat foo bar | tee -a bar >/dev/null` appears to almost work. the result is a `bar` containing copies of bar+foo+bar+foo. I haven't figured that one out. Why the last foo? Or would that be inconsistent based on `tee`'s possibly varying read of the length of `bar`?

Comment: Yes, behaving identically across shells is expected, since this is a function of GNU `cat`, and it's the same `cat` in use (a BSD one, without the check, in your case) whether your shell is bash or /bin/sh.

Answer (score 0):

```
~$ echo hello > f1
~$ echo world > f2
```

Using tmp file:

```
~$ cat f1 f2 > tmp && cat tmp >> f1 && rm tmp
~$ cat f1
hello
hello
world
```

Using tee -a:

```
~$ cat f1 f2 | tee -a f1
hello
world
~$ cat f1
hello
hello
world
```

Using paste:

```
~$ paste -d"\n" f1 f2 >> f1
~$ cat f1
hello
hello
world
```

Using bash's printf:

```
$ printf "%s\n%s\n" "$(<f1)"  "$(<f2)" >> f1
$ cat f1
hello
hello
world
```

Comment: You'd better quote `"$(<f1)"` and `"$(<f2)"` or you'll be surprised  by the results.

Comment: This works fine for short files. If we were dealing with megabytes or gigabytes...

Answer (score 0):

The proper solution is to use a temporary file.

One way to use a temporary file is to use a tool that does so invisibly. `sed`, for example:

```
$ printf 'one\ntwo\n' >foo
$ printf 'three\nfour\n' >bar
$ sed -i '' '$rbar' foo
$ cat foo
one
two
three
four
```

Or, to emulate what you were trying to do in your first example:

```
$ printf 'one\ntwo\n' >foo
$ printf 'three\nfour\n' >bar
$ sed -i '' -e '$rbar' -e '$rbar' foo
$ cat foo
one
two
three
four
three
four
```

You can adjust the sed options for your operating system of course.

Comment: The OP is using `>>`, not `>`. There's thus no truncation operation. Which is to say -- I think you're mistaking this for a more common variant on the OP's error.

Answer (score 0):

Using a temp file:

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
cat f2 f1 f2 > "$tmp" &&
  ln -f "$tmp" f2 &&
  rm "$tmp"
```